# ASP.NET MVC: Session closing and forcing login even with "Remember me"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I seem to have an issue in my MVC web application where the user is being timeouted out if they're inactive for a period of time, around 20-30 minutes I would say. After they're timed out, whether they've selected the remember me checkbox or not, they're logged out.

I'm using the authentication service that comes with a new MVC project, FormsAuthenticationService to sign in and set the .ASPAUTH cookie

```
public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
}
```

The cookie is set correctly, with a expiry date set in the future. I've also set my web.config up with the following settings:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
           timeout="2880" 
           slidingExpiration="false" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2881"></sessionState>
```

I've also set all the settings I can think of in IIS that might do this including the idle timeout setting on the app pool (which was suspiciously set at 20 minutes) to `480 minutes`.

Why is my session timing out, causing users to have to login in again? How can I make it so a user is not logged out when their 'remember me' cookie is set?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Remember me" with ASP.NET MVC Authentication is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513949/remember-me-with-asp-net-mvc-authentication-is-not-working)

Comment: Do you have the firecookie plugin for firefox? you could use that to see which cookies are being sent/received.

Comment: Cookie is set with an expiry date in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Me doesn't keep you logged in. It just remembers your Username for next time you log in.

I'm interested why you are being logged out after 20 minutes when you have set the timeout in web.config though. If you use firebug and check the expiry date of the auth cookie, what does it say?

Some other ideas:

1. Use persistent auth cookie with your SignIn() method
2. Set FormsAuthentication  SlidingExpiration true in web.config
3. Set compilation debug="false" in web.config to stop appdomain reboots
4. Check the time on the server is correct - it uses this to compare with the cookie
5. Check you're editing the right `web.config` file - I've accidentally made changes to the one in `Views` before :)

Comment: I thought that was the browser's responsibility?

Comment: If I 'Remember me', login and close the browser, when I reopen a page that needs authentication I don't need to login again. If I don't 'Remember me', I need to log in. That's what I thought the default MVC was supposed to do.

Comment: Actually I think what you describe there is what happens when you request a persistent cookie with `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);`

Comment: A persistent cookie can still time out. If you have your timeout set to 20 minutes MVC is not going to automatically log you in when you visit the site again. Set the timeout on the cookie to a longer duration like Zootius said. The "Remember Me" basically means that the cookie wont' be deleted when the user closes the browser (like session cookies are). It won't mean they never have to log in.

Comment: Also don't mistake the session timeout (set on the app pool) with the auth timeout (set on the cookie. They mean different things. 20mins for a session timeout is about normal. lengthening if for no good reason is considered a security risk

Comment: Thanks for you comments guys.
@Zootius - re:comment yeah that's what I mean when I talk of 'Remember me'
@Dismissile - agreed, that's exactly what I want to do but from what I've set in the web.config, that should already be happening, no?
@Simon Halsey - +1 thanks, good to know

Comment: re: answer edit, the expiry date is set 48 hours in the future, it's definitely not expiring. 1) That's what i'm doing here: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);`. createPersistentCookie is a bool set by a checkbox when they login. Will try other suggestions. Thanks heaps!